# insert 2 input array in database(php&jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, database

I have a page where 2 data is placed by admin.
The first option is the name and the second option is the file link that is uploaded by CKfinder.
The admin can add the number of inputs to their required number ( Using class="n-add-gallery" ).
But the problem is that only the last field 2 data is stored in the database.
I think the problem is with the array ($names and $music) and foreach loop .(( in the server.php file))

file new.php

```
    if (!isset($_GET['gallery']) && !isset($_GET['etr']) && isset($_GET['music'])){
    ?>
    <form action="server.php?server=music&id=<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="post">

        <div class="n-add-gallery">
            <a id="n-add" href="#">add<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div><!--add-->

        <div class="main">

            <span id="n-music">
                <div class="n-img1">

                    <label>names</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name1" name="name[]"/>

                    <label>file</label>
                    <input type="text" name="url[]" id="url1" READONLY/>
                    <span class="n-select" onclick="openPopup(1)">choose</span>


                </div><!--n-img-->
            </span><!--add-gallery-->
            <div id="n-insert"><button>ذخیره مداحی</button></div>

        </div><!--main-->
    </form>
<?
}
?>
```

Script to add name and link entries

```
<script>
var i=2;
$('#n-add').click(function () {
    var input=$('#url'+(i-1)+' ').val();
    if (input!="") {
        $('#n-music').append('<div class="n-img'+i+'">\n' +
            '                    <label>نام مداحی</label>\n' +
            '                    <input type="text" id="name'+i+'" name="name[]""/>\n' +
            '                    <label>انتخاب فایل</label>\n' +
            '                    <input type="text" name="url[]" id="url'+i+'" READONLY/>\n' +
            '                    <span class="n-select" onclick="openPopup('+i+')">انتخاب فایل</span>\n' +
            '                    <span class="n-del"><i onclick="dele('+i+')" class="fa fa-trash fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>\n' +
            '                </div>');
        i++;
    }
})
</script>
```

Php file for database connection

```
    class db {
    public $connect;
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $dsn="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=etrharam_db;charset=utf8";

    public function __construct(){
        $this->connect= new PDO($this->dsn,$this->username,$this->password);
        return $this->connect;
    }/*connection*/

    public function Idu($query,$data){
        $pre=$this->connect->prepare($query);
        foreach($data as $index=>$val){
            $pre->bindValue($index+1,$val);
        }
        $pre->execute();
    }/*idu*/
}
```

server.php file

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include ("oop.php");
$oop=new db();

if (isset($_GET['server'])){
    $server=$_GET['server'];


if ($server=='music'){
    $id_music=$_GET['id'];
    $music=$_POST['url'];
    $names=$_POST['name'];
    foreach (array_combine($music,$names) as $url => $name){
        $query="INSERT INTO `music_tbl`(`music`, `name`, `newcoll_id`) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $data=array($url,$name,$id_music);
        $res=$oop->Idu($query,$data);
        print_r($res);
    }//foreach
    header('location:dashboard.php');
}//if ($server=='music'){
}
```

Comment: What does `array_combine($music, $names); ` return?

Comment: What about your `$id_music`? apparently, it has a fixed value. So in case it is a primary key in your table then it's most likely that one of the insertions execute successfully and the others throw errors...

Comment: Read the input array one by one and insert to database

Comment: **$id_music** is an external key on the table.
Yes, its value is now fixed